# Is conormal sheaf a pullback?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, pullback

Apologize if this is a newbie question.

Let $i: Z\hookrightarrow X$ be a closed immersion with ideal sheaf $\mathscr{I}$. The conormal sheaf of $Z$ in $X$ is defined as $\mathscr{I}/\mathscr{I}^2$, regarded as a sheaf on $Z$.

Can the conormal sheaf be interpreted as $i^*\mathscr{I}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
$$\mathscr I/\mathscr I^2=\mathscr I\otimes_{\mathcal O_X}\mathcal O_X/\mathscr I=i^*\mathscr I.$$
This is mentioned [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01R3).

Comment: Thank you. Guess a follow up question is why is this not mentioned/remarked in most introductory text(s)?

Comment: @aaaacb you are not alone. When I was beginning with AG, I also had the same question and follow-up question for a while!